# react native how to generate .IPA file for iphone real device

Tags: ios, react-native, ipa

so I want to generate.IPA file and send it by email to another use so he can test the app on IOS device

I try to generate.IPA file with archive and then send the.IPA file

but it is not working

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly install ipa like apk in android. You can use 3rd party distribution. You have to upload your ipa on [installOnAir](https://www.installonair.com/) or [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/)

and it will generate a link open that in your phone and that will have install button there and you can install app on your phone

Note: you will only be able to app on devices which UDID's are added in App Store

Comment: thanks a lot but is there any way that i can install the app on any device without the UDID's thing

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not possible in iPhones